# Embedding Flutter app from external source in Android app at runtime

Tags: java, android, flutter, dart, flutter-android

I am trying to embed a Flutter app into an existing Android app at runtime. The Flutter app is hosted on an EC2 server and can be downloaded as a zip file from a CDN.

I have been looking at the FlutterActivity class as a potential solution, but have not been able to find any methods or properties that allow me to achieve this. Is it possible to embed a Flutter app from an external source in this way, and if so, what is the recommended approach? Any guidance or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

I have been trying to use the FlutterActivity class to embed the Flutter app into my Android app, but have not been able to find any methods or properties that allow me to do so. I have not yet tried any other approaches, as I was hoping to use the FlutterActivity class to achieve this.

I was expecting to be able to use the FlutterActivity class to load the Flutter app from the EC2 server and display it within my Android app at runtime. However, I have not been able to find any documentation or examples that demonstrate how to do this using the FlutterActivity class.

Comment: Last I checked, Flutter apps get compiled to APKs. If so, you cannot do what you are describing. You could download an APK and request to install it, but the user will need to approve this and could decline. But, if the user agrees, your main app could start some activity in the second app -- it is unclear if this is what you mean by "embed". You may also need to file some paperwork with Google to justify this behavior, if you plan on distributing your main app through Google Play.

Comment: @CommonsWare - Let’s imagine you have an app. In that app you have a button. When that button is clicked, I want to render / load / embed a new Flutter screen / app, that is outside (ex: on ec2 server).

I have seen many apps that are doing this, but they are rendering react native apps, instead of Flutter.